# Cannot boot from usb

Tags: boot, usb

I've got the next problem: I decided to install lubuntu instead of Windows on my old PC (2GB DDR2, gt220, Intel Core 2 Duo stuff). Motherboard is ga-g31m-es2l, Award BIOS.

By some reason, I couldn't boot from usb(I've set boot priority to usb, 1st boot device was hard disk, everything was fine and been done as lotta websites suggest to do).

Then I decided to install lubuntu via Unetbootin, but, by my mistake, I've formatted whole disks and therefore Unetbootin was also deleted, so now I can't boot even Windows on PC (yeah, so stupid move by me). The problem still occurs and I still can't boot from USB (but I can boot from this USB from my laptop). Even now, when I've set USB with Windows instead of lubuntu, it doesn't work anyways. Any suggestions? Should I try to update BIOS via Q-Flash, if I can to do so using BIOS?

Another option is to unplug the HDD and connect it to my laptop in order to install OS via it. But I hope there's another option.

Comment: Does your Unetbootin-created disk have the folder EFI/BOOT/ on it?  If not your drive is probably only bootable via the old MBR boot method.  If that's the case it only works on machines with legacy BIOS or UEFI with BIOS compatibility enabled.  You might need another disk writer in that case, maybe rufus.

Comment: I've rewritten usb with rufus, it still doesn't work on pc, described above, but works on laptop

Comment: Btw there's boot folder on usb driver

Comment: Unless it's /boot when booted in linux (What you're looking for is X:/EFI/BOOT/ in the outer partition visible then the drive is attached to a windows computer) that kills my idea.  There's a reason this wasn't an answer.  You might still need to go into the BIOS and mess with boot settings but that's all I've got.  Maybe burn the ISO to a DVD and try it the old fashioned way?

Comment: Well, dvd might really help, but I can't burn ISO to a DVD using laptop, only via PC, but, as I mentioned, right now it kinda has no OS on hdd. Seems like I've tried all the variants I could have messing boot settings there, well. Thank you, anyways.